# Forming URLs in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have set `enablePrettyUrl` to `true` and `showScriptName` to `false` in my Yii2 config file. My default controller is called `public`.

I also have those 2 rules:

```
[
    'pattern' => '<category_id:\w{6}>/<product_id:\w{6}>/<slug:.*?$>/',
    'route' => 'public/product',
    'defaults' => [
        'seo_url' => ''
    ]
],
[
    'pattern' => 'public/<category_id:\d{6}>/<product_id:\d{6}>/<slug:.*?$>/',
    'route' => 'public/product',
    'defaults' => [
        'seo_url' => ''
    ]
]
```

that allow me to access a product in my page with the following URL:

```
http://example.com/123456/987654/this-is-a-prodduct-example-url
```

Now, I'd expect this:

```
Url::to(["/product", "category_id" => 123456, "product_id" => 98765, "slug" => "this-is-a-product-example-url"]);
```

to form any of those:

```
/123456/987654/this-is-a-product-example-url
/product/123456/987654/this-is-a-product-example-url
/public/product/123456/987654/this-is-a-product-example-url
```

but instead I'm getting this:

```
/product/?category_id=123456&product_id=987654&slug=this-is-a-product-example-url
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe `['public/product', ...]` instead of `['product', ...]`?

Answer (score 1):

1. In pattern, most probably, you've meant  since you're using digits, not letters.
2. For a single controller-action-parameters you can have multiple rules but only the first one will be used when forming URL.
3. You're using /product but it should always be internal route i.e. controller/action or module/controller/action.

Comment: For 1, that is actually correct, as the id could contain letters too. For 2 and 3, yes, and I'd expect the first rule to be matched and used, but that is not the case. I also tried with `/public/product` (with annd without slash at the beginning) and the result is the same.

Comment: What's empty seo_url for?

Comment: I want it to default to `''` instead of `null` if I don't pass it when forming a URL.

Comment: You can specify default in action i.e. public function `actionSomething($seo_url = '')`